# JSF 2.0 Composite Component Button action can not be set via cc:attribute

Tags: jsf-2, spring-webflow

i want to build a composite component already holding some buttons with the possibility for the user to add some others.

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="action" required="false" default="cancel" targets="idCancelButton" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <h:panelGroup 
        layout="block"
        style="margin: 10px 0 10px 0; text-align: right;"
        styleClass="commandButtons">
        <composite:insertChildren />
        <p:spacer width="10" height="10" />
        <h:commandButton
            id="idCancelButton"
            value="Cancel"
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:panelGroup>
</composite:implementation>
```

A call to the component would look like this

```
<buttons:cancelButtonGroup>
    <p:commandButton id="idSaveButton" action="save" value="save" />
</buttons:cancelButtonGroup>
```

I am using Primefaces (3.0M2) (p:commandButton) with Spring Webflow and Mojarra 2.0.6 on Jetty 6.
As already described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851708/how-to-pass-a-action-string-into-a-jsf-2-composite-component) using action as attribute name with targets is working fine. Only problem is, that is possibly want to use more than one predefined button inside the component. Then the action attribute wont work anymore. I have been playing around a lot but I can not get a working version where I change the attribute to cancelAction and reference it via action="#{cc.attrs.action}" from the button. Note that as I am using Spring Webflow, cancel is the name of my transition! I do not want to call some function with return type String. I always get the exception:

```
2011-07-28 11:15:30,071 [12832806@qtp-10183200-3] WARN  exceptionHandler:185 - Handler execution resulted in exception
org.springframework.webflow.execution.FlowExecutionException: Exception thrown in state 'managePhysicalHost' of flow 'host/manageHost'
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.wrap(FlowExecutionImpl.java:569)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:263)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at info.novatec.np.server.web.filter.ConfigurableDelegatingFilter.doFilter(ConfigurableDelegatingFilter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:943)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: Unable to resolve composite component from using page using EL expression '#{cc.attrs.cancelAction}'
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl$AttributeLookupMethodExpression.invoke(TagAttributeImpl.java:444)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowActionListener.processAction(FlowActionListener.java:81)
    at org.springframework.faces.model.SelectionTrackingActionListener.processAction(SelectionTrackingActionListener.java:55)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:787)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1252)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowLifecycle.invokePhase(FlowLifecycle.java:127)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowLifecycle.execute(FlowLifecycle.java:70)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfView.processUserEvent(JsfView.java:114)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:248)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:218)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:259)
    ... 31 more
2011-07-28 11:15:30,074 [12832806@qtp-10183200-3] ERROR org.mortbay.log:87 - /ui/main
org.springframework.webflow.execution.FlowExecutionException: Exception thrown in state 'managePhysicalHost' of flow 'host/manageHost'
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.wrap(FlowExecutionImpl.java:569)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:263)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at info.novatec.np.server.web.filter.ConfigurableDelegatingFilter.doFilter(ConfigurableDelegatingFilter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:943)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: Unable to resolve composite component from using page using EL expression '#{cc.attrs.cancelAction}'
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl$AttributeLookupMethodExpression.invoke(TagAttributeImpl.java:444)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowActionListener.processAction(FlowActionListener.java:81)
    at org.springframework.faces.model.SelectionTrackingActionListener.processAction(SelectionTrackingActionListener.java:55)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:787)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1252)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowLifecycle.invokePhase(FlowLifecycle.java:127)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowLifecycle.execute(FlowLifecycle.java:70)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfView.processUserEvent(JsfView.java:114)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:248)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:218)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:259)
    ... 31 more
vax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:787)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1252)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowLifecycle.invokePhase(FlowLifecycle.java:127)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowLifecycle.execute(FlowLifecycle.java:70)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfView.processUserEvent(JsfView.java:114)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:248)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:218)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:259)
    ... 31 more
```

I have been reading lots and lots of post and articles about composite component but nobody seems to be mixing them with Spring Webflow. Or it is not noteworthy and my problems is burried somewhere else. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is a [JSF spec error](http://old.nabble.com/composite-components%3a-optional-method-expression-attributes-td30067392.html).