# jsf 2.0 - Pass an outcome as string into a composite component

Tags: parameters, jsf-2, composite-component, commandlink

I'm creating a simple composite component with jsf2, and i'm stucked because of a stupid problem.

I don't know how to send to the composite an outcome as parameter, which will be used as action on a commandLink.

Exemple :

```
<!-- Usage -->
<my:comp myAction="myOutcome" />

<!-- Component -->
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="myAction" required="true" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <h:form>
        <h:commandLink action="#{cc.attrs.myAction}" value="Go" />
    </h:form>
</composite:implementation>

<!-- Expected result -->
<h:form><h:commandLink action="myOutcome" value="Go" /></h:form>
```

I have read this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851708/how-to-pass-a-action-string-into-a-jsf-2-composite-component), but without success.

The only solution i've found is to use a managed-bean as redirector :

```
<h:commandLink action="#{redirectorBean.go(cc.attrs.myMaction)}" value="Go" />.
```

Someone could help me to achieve this with a better (simpler) solution ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute name **must** be `action` and you need to specify the composite attribute's `targets` attribute which refers the relative commandlink client ID.

Usage:

```xml
<my:comp action="myOutcome" />
```

Composite component:

```xml
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="action" targets="form:go" required="true" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <h:form id="form">
        <h:commandLink id="go" value="Go" />
    </h:form>
</composite:implementation>
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried this method but without the **"form:"**, it's why it didn't work.